# Превращает весь текст в null

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, str-replace

Используя регулярные выражения, пытаюсь оставить только почту. Но на выходе ловлю exc и finished with non-zero exit value 1. Проверил, оказывается, оно почему-то удаляет весь текст. Не совсем понимаю, какие только выражения не подбираю, все скатывается к null

```
    private static String mails;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = Util.getInput("mailsAndPasswords");
    System.out.println(transform(input));
}

    public static String transform(String input) throws Exception {
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        mails = input.replaceAll("\\b.*[A-ZА-Я]+[a-zа-я]*.", "");
        sb.append(mails);


        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: В input файле строки вида
GreedIsGood;w3@mail.com

Comment: Вы хотите вернуть список всех адресов эл. почты? Может, этот код вам поможет - https://ideone.com/GKSeL3?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew вариант неплохой, но хочется реализовать именно через вариант выше, без эррей листов. Пробовал через паттерны и матчи(используя регулярку \b[3a-zа-я@.]*), результат тот же. Просто хочу понять, что является причиной

Comment: Причина проста: `.replaceAll("\\b.*[A-ZА-Я]+[a-zа-я]*.", "")` находит и удаляет найденные совпадения. Ищет он границу слова, потом любые 0+ знаков, отличных от перевода строки, как можно больше, после которых должна быть одна заглавная буква, а потом опиционально строчные буквы, а потом любой знак, отличный от перевода строки. Вместо коллекции найденных совпадений, вы удаляете какой-то текст.

Comment: Вроде ведь все правильно. Он должен удалять определенный текст(но не почту). А он все трет. Сейчас покажу реализацию через regex pattern&matcher, там такой же результат

Comment: Лучше приведите текст в переменной `input` и желаемый результат (и его тип).

Comment: О, получилось через паттерны. Правда не совсем понимаю, почему и откуда там null'и, если я делаю compile по нужным мне символам